# What's the difference between: Is it ok for you?, and: Is it ok with you?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference and in which context you can use:

Is it ok for you?

or:

Is it ok with you?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is it OK for you?

would be asked in order to confirm whether something provided for the other person is suitable for them, e.g. after giving them a cup of coffee.

> Is it OK with you?

would be asked in order to gain agreement from the other person that a proposal is acceptable, e.g. "Is it OK with you if we meet at 6 instead of 7?"

Incidentally, the emphasis in the pronunciation is generally not the same for both.  In the first the stress is usually on the "K" of "OK".  In the second, the stress is on "you".

Answer (score 7):

ELL is the right place for posting such doubts.

Keeping it simple,when we say something is **ok with us**, it means that it is agreeable to us.
However, when we say something is **ok for us**, it means that it is convenient for us. For example:

A: How about having Korean food for dinner tonight?

B: Sure. That’s ok **with** me. I like Korean food.

A: I’d like to get together with you at 3:00 this afternoon. Is that time ok **for** you?

B: I’m afraid not. I have another appointment at 3:00, but 4:30 is ok **for** me.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these sentences are grammatically correct on their own. And the second sentence would probably not work in context either. I think the phrase that you are looking for is:

> Is that OK with you?

Hopefully this is helpful, also, I suggest posting in ELL with questions like these. I think the moderator will move this there.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it to 'Is it' if that's helpful.

Comment: @kenorb Yes, that would work better, refer to Phil's answer for when to use the statements. e.g. "Is that coffee OK for you" and "I'm going to the store, is that OK with you?" and "Is it OK with you if I postpone until Thursday"